# React DropdownButton

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to use DropdownButton to change the language on my website. I managed with Select and changing the language works. Unfortunately there is a problem with img placement in Select so I wanted to do it with DropdownButton. And here I have a problem with getting the value from Dropdown.Item.

I get the message: `Uncaught TypeError: evt is null`. What should I do in such a situation

```
const DropdownLanguage = () => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("pl");

  const handleLangChange = (evt) => {
    const lang = evt.target.value;
    console.log(lang);
    setLanguage(lang);
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DropdownButton
        id="dropdown-basic-button"
        title="Dropdown button"
        value={language}
        onSelect={handleLangChange}
      >
        <Dropdown.Item value="pl">
          <img className="flag" src={PL} />
          PL
        </Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item value="en">
          <img className="flag" src={UK} />
          EN
        </Dropdown.Item>
      </DropdownButton>
    </>
  );
}
```

I checked the documentation in React Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

I was reading the react bootstrap documentation and I see that maybe it's the problem.

The select callback sends you 2 parameters, the first is the eventKey and the second is the event.

OnSelect function description:

A callback fired when a menu item is selected.

(eventKey: any, event: Object) => any

Try changing your handleChange funciton:

```
 const handleLangChange = (evtKey, evt) => {
 const lang = evt.target.value;
 console.log(lang);
 setLanguage(lang);
 i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
 };
```

Good luck!!

Comment: No, the event handler is no the issue here, `eventKey` is null **because they didn't set the `eventKey` attribute**. Also, `evt.target` is an HTML Element DOM node for the `<a>` link object, which has no `value` attribute, so you'd have to use `evt.target.getAttribute("value")`. Way too much effort when just setting `eventKey` will do.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/), `DropdownButton` doesn't have prop `onSelect`. `onSelect` is only existed in `Dropdown`, so you can change from `DropdownButton` to `Dropdown`.

Comment: DropdownButton passes on the remaining attributes to Dropdown.Menu, which is the inner component handling the items. It does have `onSelect`. In fact, `DropdownButton` **creates the `Dropdown` _for you_**, that's its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [`selectKey` attribute](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/#dropdown-item-props) on your `Dropdown.Item` components. From the documentation for `Dropdown.Item`:

> | Name | Type | Default | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... |
> | eventKey | string | number |  | Value passed to the `onSelect` handler, useful for identifying the selected menu item. |

and note the [documentation on `Dropdown.onEvent`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/#dropdown-menu-props), where the first argument name is `eventKey`:

> | Name | Type | Default | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... |
> | onSelect | function |  | A callback fired when a menu item is selected. `(eventKey: any, event: Object) => any` |

Note that `DropdownButton` is a convenience component, it wraps a `Dropdown` component with nested `Dropdown.Toggle` and `Dropdown.Menu` components, with any `Dropdown.Item` components used to populate the `Dropdown.Menu` children.

You may have mistakenly used a `value` attribute instead of `eventKey` here. Replacing `value` with `eventKey` works, the value of this property is passed directly to your handler as the first argument:

```
const DropdownLanguage = () => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("pl");

  const handleLangChange = (lang) => {
    console.log(lang);
    setLanguage(lang);
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DropdownButton
        id="dropdown-basic-button"
        title="Dropdown button"
        onSelect={handleLangChange}
      >
        <Dropdown.Item eventKey="pl" active={language === 'pl'}>
          <img className="flag" src={PL} />
          PL
        </Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item eventKey="en" active={language === 'en'}>
          <img className="flag" src={UK} />
          EN
        </Dropdown.Item>
      </DropdownButton>
    </>
  );
}
```

Note that `DropdownButton` has no `value` property, either. Instead, to pick a specific menu option as the selected item, set the `active` property of the selected `Dropdown.Item` to true.

Here is an online sandbox to demonstrate:

[image: Edit React-Bootstrap language picker]

You could otherwise access the event object itself (and `event.target`) if you give your `handleLangChange()` handler a second argument to receive it, or you can use `arguments[1]`. You'll have to use a DOM method in that case, like `event.target.getAttribute("value")`, to access any attributes. But that's really overkill here.